Given a set of integers show that three must sum to zero
This is a problem found in a PigeonHole Principle handout by Valentin Garanko:

Given $2m+1$ distinct integers with absolute value $\leq2m-1$
Show that there are three integers whose sum is zero.

I am assuming there is something easy I have missed, but I spent a lot of effort trying to prove it so I would like to know if anyone else has an answer. Below I have included some ideas that I tried out.
First of all, it is trivial to show this sum exists if zero is included in the set so we will exclude it.
Initially considering the problem we have a set of integers $$ A = \{a_1,a_2...a_{2m+1}|1 \leq a_1 \leq a_2 \leq...a_k \leq 2m-1\}$$ and it is clear by PHP that there are at least 2 $a_i$ such that $(a_i,-a_i)$ exist. By considering the set of $a_i$ with this property is it possible to construct a partial solution.
Let us take this set and rename it $S$ for its symmetric property and let us only consider the positive part of the pairs
$$S = \{s_1,s_2...s_k | s_1 < s_2 ... < s_k\}.$$
Now by considering the set of the differences between $s_k$ and each $s_i$ we know each difference is a unique positive integer $\leq2m-1$:
$$ S_D = \{s_k-s_1,s_k-s_2...s_k-s_{k-1}\} $$
Now given that there are $k$ positive numbers in the set $A$ with the symmetric property we know that there are $2m+1 - 2k$ unique integers without this property. We also known that we have a set of $k-1$ unique differences. Consider the absolute value of all $A$, given there are $k$ symmetric numbers and $2m+1 - 2k$ unique numbers we see that $2m+1 - k$ positive numbers are uniquely characterized. If we consider the $k-1$ differences $2m$ numbers are characterized. Meaning the $k-1$ difference must overlap with either the $k$ symmetric numbers or the absolute values of the $2m+1 - 2k$ unique numbers Therefore, for some $a_i$:
$$ s_k-s_i = |a_i|$$
What is useful about the symmetric numbers is that if $a_i$ is negative it can be added to the left side such that
$$s_k-s_i+a_i = 0 $$
and if it is positive we can add over $s_k$ and $s_i$ such that
$$a_i-s_k+s_i = 0 $$
and since both $(s_i,-s_i)$ exist in $A$ our proof in concluded.
However, there is a fatal flaw in this proof, in the case that $s_k-s_i=s_i$ for some $s_i$ we have only characterized $2m-1$ of the positive integers and there is no guaranteed sum that gives $0$.
Equivalently phrased as: if within S $s_k = 2s_i$ we cannot construct a sum of zero using 3 distinct integers.
I also considered trying to restrict the possible solution set in $3d$ space $(x,y,z)$ but was unable to narrow it down enough. We have $(2m+1)(2m)(2m-1)$ possible solutions within a cube of side length $4m-2$, and must show the possible solutions overlaps with the plane of solutions characterized by $x+y+z = 0$ along with other restrictions.
Any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

With $m=1$ you have to pick $2m+1 = 3$ distinct integers out of $\{-1,0,1\} = \{z \in \mathbb Z : |z| \leq 1\}$. There's only one way to do that and the numbers end up summing to zero, so we're done.
Let $S_k = \{z \in \mathbb Z : |z| \leq k\}$, $k \in \mathbb N$.
Now, let's do induction. Assuming the statement holds for $m \geq 1$, Let $S \subset S_{2m+1}, |S| = 2m+3$. There are four numbers $S' = \{\pm 2m, \pm (2m+1)\} = S_{2m+1} \setminus S_{2m-1}$ which have absolute value $2m$ or $2m+1$. We use this to break the analysis into cases.

If $|S \cap S'| \leq 2$ then $|S \cap S_{2m-1}| = |S| - |S \setminus S'| \geq 2(m+1)+1 - 2 \geq 2m+1$. So then, $S \cap S_{2m-1} \subset S_{2m-1}$ is a subset of size at least $2m+1$ and hence contains three elements which sum to $0$. These elements are also contained in $S$, so we're done.

If $|S \cap S'| = 3$, then $S$ must contain either both $\pm 2m$ or both $\pm(2m+1)$. Either way, if $S$ contains $0$ then we are in trouble, so from now on we assume that $S$ doesn't contain $0$. Then, $S \cap (S_{2m-1} \setminus \{0\})$ has size $2(m+1)+1 - 3 = 2m$.
Suppose that $S$ contains $\pm(2m+1)$. Consider the sets $$\{\pm 1, \pm 2m\}, \{\pm 2, \pm (2m-1)\},\{\pm 3 , \pm(2m-2)\}, \ldots, \{\pm m, \pm(m+1)\}$$
Now, suppose that $S$ contains three elements from any of these sets. Then it contains two elements with the same sign whose sum of magnitudes is $2m+1$, which gives rise to three elements in $S$ whose sum is zero. So, $S$ must contain at most two elements from each set, but it already contains one element from $\pm 2m$, so it contains at most one element out of $\pm 1$ and two each out of $\{\pm 2, \pm (2m-1)\},\{\pm 3 , \pm(2m-2)\}, \ldots, \{\pm m, \pm(m+1)\}$. This implies that $|S \cap (S_{2m-1} \setminus \{0\})| \leq 2(m-1)+1 = 2m-1$ which contradicts our earlier statement that the set had size $2m$.
The only way to resolve our contradictions is either if $S$ contained $0$ or if $S$ contained more than two elements from any of the considered sets, providing a proof.
Suppose that $S$ contains $\pm(2m)$, then an analogous argument follows. It's easy to see that $S$ contains only one element out of $\pm 1$ since $S$ also contains one of $\pm(2m+1)$. Consider the sets $$\{\pm 2, \pm(2m-2)\}, \{\pm 3, \pm (2m-3)\},\ldots, \{\pm (m-1) , \pm(m+1)\}, \{\pm m\}$$
If $S$ contains three elements from any of the sets other than $\{\pm m\}$, then it contains two elements with the same sign whose sum of magnitudes is $2m$, which gives rise to three elements in $S$ whose sum is zero. So, $S$ must contain at most two elements from each set including $\{\pm m\}$. This implies that $|S \cap (S_{2m-1} \setminus \{0\})| \leq 2(m-1)+1 = 2m-1$ which contradicts our earlier statement that the set had size $2m$.
The only way to resolve our contradictions is either if $S$ contained $0$ or if $S$ contained more than two elements from any of the considered sets, providing a proof.

Finally, if $|S \cap S'| = 4$ then $S$ contains all of $\pm 2m, \pm (2m-1)$, but then clearly $S$ doesn't contain $1,0$ or $-1$, and hence $|S \cap (S_{2m-1} \setminus \{-1,0,1\})| = 2(m+1)+1-4 = 2m-1$.
Again, consider the sets $$
\{\pm 2, \pm (2m-1)\},\{\pm 3 , \pm(2m-2)\}, \ldots, \{\pm m, \pm(m+1)\}
$$
$S$ can only contain up to $2$ elements from each of these sets and there are $m-1$ of them, so $|S \cap (S_{2m-1} \setminus \{-1,0,1\})| \leq 2m-2$, giving a contradiction.
The only way to resolve our contradictions is either if $S$ contained one of $0,1$ or $-1$, or if $S$ contained more than two elements from any of the considered sets, finishing the argument.
